# Getting Azure Blob Store Eventgrid Notifications from another Azure Account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

we work with an other company who just proposed us to privide us with an azure blob store SAS token. But we would like to use the events triggered by the Blob store and provided by the Azure Eventgrid system.

Is this possible ?

Why we have to this on our azure account is for billing purposes, we need the Events they don't we will have to pay for through our account

I hope someone can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

[Azure Blob Storage as an Event Grid source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage) works for `Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated` and `Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted` and when an event is triggered, the Event Grid service sends data about that event to the subscribing endpoint.  Those event grid subscriptions exist in the same Azure Subscription as the resources.

[Webhook Event delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery) is one of the many ways to receive events from Azure Event Grid and this is something you can host in your Azure Subscription (or even outside of Azure).

Given the **Price per million operations** is only $0.60 per the [Event Grid Basic tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-grid/), the Webhook notification will allow you to pay for all but a negligible amount of the costs.